# Understanding identified prime paths in the prime path coverage example given

Tags: automated-testing, coverage, whitebox-testing

I'm trying to understand this example in paper [Code coverage and test automation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.11723). Please refer to the figure.

Why is `(n3, n4, n1, n3)` a prime path, while `(n3, n4, n1, n2)` is not?

[image: Prime path coverage example]

Comment: The imagine is a bit confusing - the outbound edges of n4 and n5 are pointing to another edge, not clearly to a node.

Comment: @JoãoFarias I agree. Let's presume they are pointing to n1. That's how I interpreted it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the list on the right-hand side is a complete list of paths.

For example, the graphic is also missing a couple paths beginning with `n_0`:

- `n_0 -> n_1 -> n_3 -> n_4`
- `n_0 -> n_1 -> n_3 -> n_5`